# Is there anyway to easily bind custom string to id and for in html element using Angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular

Consider the following [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jmFUHNCxMekxOmBp0gEy?p=preview)

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="#option of myHashMap">
        <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="{{generateId(option['id'])}}">
        <label for="{{generateId(option['id'])}}">
            {{option['name']}}
        </label>
    </div>        
    `
})
export class App {

    myHashMap = [{'name': 'myName1', 'id': 'id1'},{'name': 'myName2', 'id': 'id2'}]

    generateId(key) {
      return "myKey" + key;
    }
}
```

I am trying to bind a string to `id` in `input` and the same string to `for` in `label`. However I run into

```
Can't bind to 'for' since it isn't a known native property ("hMap">
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="
```

Is there an angular2 idiomatic way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`id`** can be bound to using one of

```
id="{{someProp}}"
[id]="someProp"
```

because **[id](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/id)** is a property on every element.

For **`for`** you need to use one of

```
[attr.for]="someProp"
attr.for="{{someProp}}"
[htmlFor]="someProp"
htmlFor="{{someProp}}"
```

because **[htmlFor](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement)** is the property that is reflected to the `for` attribute.

See also [Properties and Attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CmrnV0?p=preview)

Comment: Why should it not work? Elements have an `id` property and binding works just fine (see Plunker link)

Comment: Hmm, I guess it still does work, but I remember having problems with my code when I did not use **[attr.id]**. In the generated HTML, there is also *ng-reflect-id="someId"* when you use **[id]**, but this attribute does not exist when you use **[attr.id]**. Though I'm not sure what ng-reflect is for.

Comment: `ng-reflect-id` is created for property-bindings and `[id]` is a property binding. Perhaps you tried binding to an `@Input() id;` which doesn't work while `[attr.id]=".."` might work (not tried myself).

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html does say "Attribute (the exception)". So maybe you're right that the property form should be preferred. I could swear it didn't work for me once, but it does now. Maybe there was a change in one of the betas/RCs I was using?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to bind attribute value:

```
[attr.id]="value"
```

Comment: This would not work with `for` though. `[attr.for]` will give error

Comment: I was wrong about `[attr.for]`, it works, I was just using it incorrectly `[attr.for]={{myVariable}}` will not work I need `[attr.for]="myVariable"`